# ServiceStack casting response to CompressedResult throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net, iis, servicestack

I have json data that is being compressed using ServiceStacks's inbuilt ToOptimizedResult method. This has been working fine for a while now, recently though, when the data to be returned is high (50k+) rows etc. I get the Out Memory Error below:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(Object value, Type type)
at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString[T](T value)
at ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.JsonDataContractSerializer.SerializeToString[T](T obj)
at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter.SerializeToString(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response)
at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RequestContextExtensions.ToOptimizedResult[T](IRequestContext requestContext, T dto)
at MyService.post(PostDDSReportDataSourceData Input) in MyService.vb:line 452
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )
at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequestContext requestContext, Object instance, TRequest request)
```

The weird part is that the exact same data is serialized ok on Dev, the error only appears in Production. The main solutions I've seen online recommend disabling buffering, however I've only seen examples that disable buffering entirely for the entire application. How can I disable buffering just for that one request?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself eventually. In the method simply turn off buffering like this:

```
CType(MyBase.Response.OriginalResponse, System.Web.HttpResponse).BufferOutput = False
```

As an addendum to the above solution, you will still receive this error if you store the json string in a variable. Only call the ToOptimized method when returning the result. Turning off buffering won't make a difference if you store the serialized string in a variable.

I eventually ended up serializing my list to a file, then sending the file down by returning an HttpResult below:

```
Dim PathToTheSerializedJsonFile as String = "C:\SomeFile.Json"

Using fl As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(PathToTheSerializedJsonFile)
  Dim Serr As New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
  Serr.Serialize(fl, Input)
End Using

Return New HttpResult(New FileInfo(PathToTheSerializedJsonFile),asAttachment:=True)
```